# Can we store database triggers just like database migrations in modern web based frameworks?

Tags: database, migration

Sometimes we need to define triggers in database for some use case. In such a scenario, how do version control the source code of triggers such that it can be replicated in all environments e.g. developement, pre-staging, staging, production.

An approach on the lines of database migrations would be good. Do we have any such thing in existence?

Answer (score 0):

There are ton of migration tools available for almost every better framework in any language to manage migrations. Do a Google search on whatever language and framework you use.